# Product Function Similar to Sum for Access 2010 SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, grouping, product, multiplication

Is there a way to simulate a Product function, similar to Sum (Including Group by)?

I was able to transpose the column in question and calculate the values I needed, but it is really slow and inefficient.

I would like to avoid using vba code, but if there isn't another way...

Thank you for your help.

Dave

Comment: I wonder if you are thinking of a crosstab? Are you trying to avoid sql?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you'll get would be a custom VBA Function to implement a domain-aggregate `DProduct()` function similar to the built-in `DSum()` function described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/dsum-function-HA001228829.aspx).

If I had to implement something like that I would probably start with a copy of Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function and hack it to multiply numeric values together instead of concatenating strings together. In other words, instead of starting with an empty string (`strOut`) and performing string concatenations within a loop...

```vbs
Do While Not rs.EOF
    ' ...
    strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
    ' ...
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

...I would start with my output variable equal to 1 and then perform multiplications within the loop

```vbs
varOut = 1
Do While Not rs.EOF
    ' ...
    varOut = varOut * rs(0)
    ' ...
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```